# Is this Syntax Correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

```
    for(var div_count=0;div_count<10;div_count++)
        {
            $("#div_"+div_count).append("<div style="'margin-left:'+incr_count+"px;>Hello<div>");
            incr_count=incr_count+ 80 ;            

        }
```

The above Code is not Working. But when i hard code the value to margin-left. It Works. I think it's a syntax pblm. can anyone correct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var div_count=0;div_count<10;div_count++)
        {
            $("#div_"+div_count).append('<div style="margin-left:'+incr_count+'px;">Hello</div>');
            incr_count=incr_count+ 80 ;            

        }
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around the style attribute and you have an unclosed `<div>`.

Comment: @Anish which one ? select the one whos answer was the most helpful; ( including the fix on the third line)

Comment: I tried both of your answers. But your answer is more specific and you point out the px (i didn't use in my actual code). Anyway i am accepting both of your answers.

Comment: can you explain me the above code (i.e)  quotes used in the code. I don't know where to put quotes...

Comment: The HTML code to use would be `<div style='margin-left: 80px;'>Hello</div>`. So to write this out in Javascript, you need to turn it into a concatenation of strings. The first string is `"<div style='margin-left:"`. Then we concatenate that with the variable `incr_count`. Finally, add the last string: `"px;'>Hello</div>"`. If you have trouble visualizing things, like this, write the basic HTML first and then split it into pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Change the third line to:

```
$("#div_"+div_count).append("<div style='margin-left:" + incr_count + "px;'>Hello</div>");
```

Comment: your answer is not complete!  hes doing `incr_count=incr_count+ 80px ;  ` which will be two "px" words in the assignments.

Answer (score 2):

```
incr_count = 0;
for(var div_count = 0; div_count < 10; div_count++) {
    $("#div_" + div_count).append(
                                $("<div>")
                                    .css("margin-left", incr_count + "px")
                                    .html("Hello")
    );
    incr_count += 80;       
}
```

Comment: Cool. I tried this one also. But i don't know where to put .css. i put it in outside append which applied to the parent element. Thanx for your code.

Comment: +1 for showing the correct way of setting style attributes with jquery